# Input on launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am using ROS Noetic and I have a a python 3 script that is being launched with a launch file. To further automatize my project, I wanted to know if it's possible to include input on the launch file to be used within the python script? And if so, How do I do it?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353946/input-on-launch-file/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best would be to create parameters in your python script. Examples [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server)  (Make them private with  `~`)

For example in my node I have :

```
self.target_frame = rospy.get_param("~target_frame", "map")
```

And  I can start it like this in in my launchfile :

```
<node pkg="robot_platform" type="test.py" name="test" output="screen">
    <param name="target_frame" value="test" />
</node>
```

This method is very good because it allows you to use the parameter server to set your parameters also and load them from a yaml file for example.

You can read more about the parameter server  [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server)

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-06-03**:
Hey! I tried your approach but on the terminal I keep getting a KeyError.
MY launch file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <node pkg="gspn_framework_package" ns="robot_1" type="gspn_execution_node.py" name="executor_1">
    <param name="user_robot_id" value="1" />
    <param name="user_current_place" value="p1" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="gspn_framework_package" ns="robot_2" type="gspn_execution_node.py" name="executor_2">
    <param name="user_robot_id" value="2" />
    <param name="user_current_place" value="p3" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

And on my Python I have:

```
namespace = rospy.get_namespace()
user_robot_id = rospy.get_param(namespace + "user_robot_id")
user_current_place = rospy.get_param(namespace + "user_current_place")
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried without the namespace but I had the same error.

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2020-06-03**:
I didnt use `rospy.get_namespace`.

If you put `~` at the beginning of your param name to set it private you shouldn't need it,

Like so :

```
user_robot_id = rospy.get_param("~user_robot_id")
user_current_place = rospy.get_param("~user_current_place")
```

Does it solve your problem ?

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-06-03**:
Sadly, I still get the KeyError. I did exactly as you told me: without using the namespace and using the "~". Maybe there's something wrong in my launch file.

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2020-06-03**:
Do you have `rospy.init_node()` in your node ?

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-06-03**:
Okay it worked! I was doing `rospy.init_node()` afterwards. Thank you :)